# Laravel Eloquent Relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Ok, I hope you've got a coffee for this one.

I have the following tables.

```
Workshops
- id
- title
- company_id

Locations
- id
- name

Workshop_Locations
- workshop_id
- location_id

Company
- id
- name

People
- id
- company_id
- name
- verified
```

I am trying to if possible create a result from the above tables but out only the verified workshops. They would be verified by the peoples table as these are linked to the companies table which in turn is linked to the workshops table.

Workshops are verified by having people that are certified assigned to them.

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? SO is here to help with specific problems, not to crowdsource code or tutorials

Comment: You need to read about Eloquent relationships if you want to do it in "Laravel way" https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships
@GarethParker is right. We can help you with some specific moments, if your code doesn't work and you don't know why. But no one will code it for you for free.

Comment: You need all  workshops that belong to companies that have at least one person(people) verified or all workshops that belong to companies that have all their people verified?

Comment: @geoandri have at least one person verified

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
$verifiedWorkshops = Workshop::select('workshops.*')
    ->join('companies', 'workshops.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->join('people', 'people.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->where('people.verified', '=', true)
    ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "Laraverish" way to achieve this is using a "has many through" relationship between workshops and people.The models then would be

```
class Workshops extends Model
{

  public function company()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
  }

  public function locations()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location');
  }

  public function people()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\People', 'App\Company');
  }
}

class Company extends Model
{
   public function workshops()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\People');
   }
}

class People extends Model
{
  public function company()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
   }
}

class Location extends Model
{

  public function workshops()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Workshop');
  }
}
```

Then you could fetch the verified workshops with the following query

```
$workshops= Workshops::whereHas('people', function ($query) {
$query->where('verified', '=', true);
})->get();
```